# postgresql9.0 locked and unresponsive if update operation performed on the row where update operation is interrupted

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, locking, postgresql-9.0

**Scenario:**

1. table has a row with `id=1`
2. update command initiated with JDBC on row `id=1` but before it gets
   committed, the java program that made the JDBC connection got
   terminated
3. Now another JDBC connection tries to update the same row `id=1`

**Observation:**

When monitoring the database, the locks are noticeable and further update operation on the same row, causes the db server to freeze up and must be restarted for normal operation...
If there are less update queries and less number of sessions, the locks gets released within a minute... but in real world apps, the update gets executed frequently and the server freezes up

**So my Question is:**

Is there a way(configuration,tools,...) to force,close and drop the locks in Postgres server for any dead db connections from client

**Code:**

```
package postgrestest;

import java.sql.*;

public class IncompleteTransvanilla implements Runnable {
    private int seq = 0;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private boolean insertoperation = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        boolean flag = true;
        if(args.length>0) {flag = false;}
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            new Thread(new IncompleteTransvanilla(i,flag)).start();
            //Thread.sleep(1000*(int)(Math.random()*10));
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    public IncompleteTransvanilla(int i, boolean flag) {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", "postgres", "postgres");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        seq=i;
        insertoperation = flag;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement;
            if(insertoperation == true) {
                System.out.println("Inserting");
                statement = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into uacc(user_id,username,password,email) values(DEFAULT,?,'samplepass','samplemail')");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Updating");
                statement = connection.prepareStatement("update uacc set username=? where user_id=1");
            }
            int maxval = 100;
            for(int i=0;i<maxval;i++) {
                statement.setString(1, "sampleuser"+((seq*maxval)+i));
                statement.execute();
            }
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            connection.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failure.");
        }
    }

}
```

**database monitoring dash screenshot for reference:**

[image: Database Monitoring - pashviewer postgres9.0 locks]

**Edit:**
any suggestion/configuration in server that can be used to auto drop such locks or config to reduce the time it it waits for the connection and drops the locks?

or... will upgrading postgres9.0 to say 9.5 fix these kinda issues?

Comment: Apparently the server does not notice that the client has disconnected. Might be a problem with the TCP configuration, normally the transaction started by the client will be rolled back if that client terminates. Does the connection from the "terminated" Java program still shows up in `pg_stat_activity`? If yes, you could simply kill that manually.

Comment: Postgres 9.0 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should really plan an upgrade now.

Comment: Your sample code does not "terminate" the Java program at all, so yes it is expected, that the locks held by that program will not be released until that connection is closed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i intentionally terminated the program to simulate the scenario... wherever i placed Thread.sleep(), i interrupted the program... the objective is to replicate realtime scenario where a pc running the java client might get a power failure... or force close of the java application

Comment: So does the connection show up in `pg_stat_activity`? On what operating system does the Postgres server run?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , yes it shows in the table `waiting=t` ... Ubuntu 18:04 64 bit bionic beaver for simulation purposes, i started the java app in the same machine localhost... server and app same machine

Comment: You could try adding `tcpKeepAlive=true` to the JDBC URL, and maybe fiddle around with the [keepalive settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE) of the server. As a last resort you can simply kill those abandoned backends using [`pg_terminate_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE). No need to restart the server

Comment: On 9.6+, you could set [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT)

Answer (score 1):

To protect against clients that suddenly die in the middle of work, you can use the following PostgreSQL parameters:

- [`tcp_keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE): Set it to a low value like 60, so that the server probes the client after a minute of inactivity and can kill the session if the client is dead.
- [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT): Set this to and even lower value, because no transaction should remain idle for a long time. This will kill sessions that are idle while holding locks. Be careful that you don't disrupt normal activity on your database!

Upgrading from 9.0 should be your first priority, since 9.0 is dangerously old and unsupported. Update to v11 rather than to 9.5 though.